# How am I able to access protected method from a class which doesn't inherit from that class?

Tags: java, methods, overloading, protected

```
public class Doubt1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Manager m1 = new Manager(25000);
        Manager m2 = new Manager(25000);``

        System.out.println(m1.getSalary(250000) + " " + m2.getSalary()); //how is m1.getSalary working when getSalary(int) is protected in Employee class
    }
}

class Employee{
    protected int salary;

    public Employee(int s){
        salary = s;
    }

    protected int getSalary(int s){
        return salary + s; 
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee{

    public Manager(int s){
        super(s);
    }
    public int getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }
}
```

I have overloaded getSalary method from Employee class in manager class. getSalaray(int) method of Employee class has protected access and hence, can only be accessed from Manager class. But when I call m1.getSalary(25000), why is the compiler not complaining about "protected access in employee class" as it does when I declare the method private? Or is protected access modifier something else than what I assume it to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Answer (score 3):

The `protected` access modifier allows more forms of access than `private`. Because the method is in the same package or subclass, the access is allowed.

More info here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 2):

`protected` method allows access by other members of the same `package`, in addition to subclasses that are not in the same package.

Access Levels Chart:

```
Modifier    Class   Package  Subclass   World
public        Y        Y        Y         Y
protected     Y        Y        Y         N
no modifier   Y        Y        N         N
private       Y        N        N         N
```

Read more in the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)